# Django Haystack and Xapian

Tags: django

I want to use Django Haystack with Xapian on my django site for search function. After setting all the necessary settings. I went ahead to input: `manage.py rebuild_index` , after inputting 'y' I'm getting an error saying:

> No module named xapian_backend.

I can see the xapian backend module in site-packages, but I don't know why Django is not seeing it. How Can I make it work?

Below is my settings:

```
import os
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
        'PATH': 'C:/Python27/Scripts/myweb/xapian_index',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'BATCH_SIZE': 100,
    },
}
```

Comment: Did you add haystack to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes I did. Still not working!

Comment: As well as the [xapian_haystack](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack) backend, do you have all its Xapian dependencies (the Xapian library, and the Xapian python bindings) installed? If you can run `python -c 'import xapian'` then these requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Engine should be:

```
'ENGINE': 'xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
```

It is not included in the haystack package, but is separate.  It probably still won't work.  It doesn't seem to have been upgraded to work with haystack 2.x.

**Update**: it has now been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by copying the xapian_backend.py to haystack/backends as suggested by the  [readme](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack)